# Extra rows for custom expression to display "filtered" sum

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

So I have a table that gets its resultset from a procedure and everything looks great, including the totals at the bottom.  The user has asked for a few custom rows at the bottom that are only to represent the totals for specific criteria or group.  Say you have a field called AuctionPrice.  In the dataset it is from an aggregate within a sql procedure.

If I place an extra row at the bottom of the table and the "AuctionPrice" field, I use an expression like this
=SUM(IIF(Fields!AuctionPrice > 0, Fields!AuctionPrice, 0))

This produced an error, whereas an expression with using a different field in the comparision works fine.

Is it true that you can not use an expression using a field that is already included in an aggregate (sum) in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ssrs expression to work you forgot to define .value after your field

The correct expression must be like the one below

`=SUM(IIF(Fields!AuctionPrice.value > 0, Fields!AuctionPrice.value, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `Fields!AuctionPrice` column has special character`(!)` in it. You need to escape it using square bracket

```
select SUM(IIF([Fields!AuctionPrice] > 0, [Fields!AuctionPrice], 0))
From yourtable
```

---

### [Rules for Regular Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

The names of variables, functions, and stored procedures must comply with the following rules for Transact-SQL identifiers.

1. The *first character* must be one of the following:

   - A letter as defined by the `Unicode Standard 3.2`. The Unicode    definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z,
     from A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
   - The underscore (`_`), at sign (`@`), or number sign (`#`).

Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning in SQL Server. A regular identifier that starts with the at sign always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be used as the name of any other type of object. An identifier that starts with a number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure. An identifier that starts with double number signs (##) denotes a global temporary object. Although the number sign or double number sign characters can be used to begin the names of other types of objects, we do not recommend this practice.

Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (`@@`). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not use names that start with `@@`.

2. Subsequent characters can include the following:

   - Letters as defined in the Unicode Standard 3.2.
   - Decimal numbers from either Basic Latin or other national scripts.
   - The at sign, dollar sign (`$`), number sign,
     or underscore.
3. The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server reserves both the uppercase and lowercase versions of reserved words. When identifiers are used in Transact-SQL statements, the identifiers that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by **double quotation marks** or **brackets**. The words that are reserved depend on the database compatibility level. This level can be set by using the `ALTER DATABASE` statement.
4. `Embedded spaces` or `special characters` are not allowed.
5. `Supplementary characters` are not allowed.

When `identifiers` are used in Transact-SQL statements, the identifiers that *do not* comply with these rules must be delimited by **double quotation marks** or **brackets**.